# prestashop assign a cookie in a module

Tags: cookies, prestashop

I would like to get the var $param from file blockcart.php in the module block cart and put it in a cookie. I'm not so good in POO so can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code.

```
public function hookAjaxCall($params)
{
    global $cookie; //mycode

    if (Configuration::get('PS_CATALOG_MODE'))
    return;

    $this->assignContentVars($params);
    $res = $this->display(__FILE__, 'blockcart-json.tpl');

    $cookie->__set('test', $param); //my code

    return $res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `__set` is a "magic method" not for use directly. Use this coding form instead:

```
$cookie->test = $params;
$cookie->write();
```

The `__set()` function will handle the assignment of the new member variable you have created. Likewise you can use:

```
global $cookie;
if (isset($cookie->test))
    // Use $cookie->test in your custom code
```